# Cannot query all Tasks with different onwerID

Tags: apex, soql, community, tasks, sharing-rule

I need to delete all tasks (Activity object) with a Set ownerId.

I noticed that when I write query on Developer Console for getting task records and I can get 10 records, but when I write query on apex class then I just get only task record that related to current user.

I have checked security and I think there are a potential solution is that implement a sharing rule to set edit for a group of user and set Org wide default to private. I am wondering there are any solution for this.

Can anyone give me some advices for this case?

Comment: do you want anybody to see anybody record ?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: No Himanshu, Task will be created for a group of user. When i login a specific user and i remove the task, and my scenario is that that task will be also disappeared from another user in that group. So i wrote a query on Apex class but it got only one task records that related to current user that login to my web.

Comment: It is just simple query @ahtnasah.li. My issue is Salesforce has secured Activity object by some way and I dont know it :(.                                       My query is : [SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE OwnerId IN: listOfUserHaveTask]

Comment: @HoangTran is Task record shared with group?

Comment: @Ratan It also shared with group. I have worked with salesforce for a long time, but this case is very strange and i dont know exactly reason :( .

Comment: Can you just check with UserRecordAccess. **SELECT Id, HasDeleteAccess FROM  UserRecordAccess WHERE RecordId =: 'YOUR RECORDId' AND UserId =: 'YOUR USER Id, don't have access ONE'**. Check `HasDeleteAccess` giving true or false. If false then issue with something sharing.

Comment: If using async job is ok, perhaps just run an @future or queueable apex job, which will get you around user context restriction.

Comment: (1) see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm -- the `without sharing` should provide access to all Tasks in apex;

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have declared your class with the 'with sharing' keyword. If you drop that keyword Apex code runs in system context. "In system context, Apex code has access to all objects and fields-object permissions, field-level security, sharing rules aren’t applied for the current user." So if that's the behaviour you looking for then just declare your class as:

```
public class YourClassName {

// Code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a class similar to the following:

```
public without sharing ClassName
{

}
```

Please ensure to use the "without sharing" keywords as not providing them leaves the class susceptible to inheriting sharing rules from any class that calls it if "with sharing" is defined.

Please see the following document for further details: [Using the with sharing or without sharing Keywords](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm)